# meaning of an entry in a relocation table of an object file

Tags: c, linker, x86-64, relocation

I met some problems in understanding the entries of relocation tables compiled from C source files.
My programs are as below:

```
//a.c
extern int shared;
int main(){
    int a = 100;
    swap(&a, &shared);
    a = 200;
    shared = 1;
    swap(&a, &shared);
}
//b.c
int shared = 1;
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    if (a != b)
        *b ^= *a ^= *b, *a ^= *b;
}
```

I compile and link them with the following commands `gcc -c -fno-stack-protector a.c b.c` and `ld a.o b.o -e main -o ab`.
Then I `objdump -r a.o` to check its relocation table.

```
RELOCATION RECORDS FOR [.text]:
OFFSET           TYPE              VALUE 
0000000000000014 R_X86_64_32       shared
0000000000000021 R_X86_64_PC32     swap-0x0000000000000004
000000000000002e R_X86_64_PC32     shared-0x0000000000000008
000000000000003b R_X86_64_32       shared
0000000000000048 R_X86_64_PC32     swap-0x0000000000000004
```

The disassembly of `a.o` is

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
0:  55                      push   %rbp
1:  48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
4:  48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
8:  c7 45 fc 64 00 00 00    movl   $0x64,-0x4(%rbp)
f:  48 8d 45 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
13: be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
18: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
1b: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
20: e8 00 00 00 00          callq  25 <main+0x25>
25: c7 45 fc c8 00 00 00    movl   $0xc8,-0x4(%rbp)
2c: c7 05 00 00 00 00 01    movl   $0x1,0x0(%rip)  # 36 <main+0x36>
33: 00 00 00 
36: 48 8d 45 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
3a: be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
3f: 48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
42: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
47: e8 00 00 00 00          callq  4c <main+0x4c>
4c: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
51: c9                      leaveq 
52: c3                      retq
```

My question is that:
`shared` at 14 and `shared` at 2e are totally the same objects. Why they have different symbol names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the same address but the relocation types are different. The relocation types are defined in [x86-64-abi](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.98.pdf).

What is the difference?

At `0x14` and `0x3b`: the address of the global variable `shared` must be moved to register `%rsi` in order to call the function `swap`.

However, because the program was compiled with `-mcmodel=small` (default for gcc, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52253518/5769463)), the compiler can assume, that the address fits into 32bit and uses `movl` instead of `movq` (actually the compiler would use other instructions otherwise, but comparing `movl` with "naive" `movq` explains the difference pretty well), which would need more bytes to be encoded.

Thus, the resulting relocation is `R_X86_64_32` (i.e. 64bit address truncated to 32bit without sign-extension) and not `R_X86_64_64`, i.e. the linker will write 4 lower bytes of the address instead of the placeholder, which is also 4 bytes wide.

At `0x2e` you would like to write the value `1` to memory address `shared`. However, the target-address is given relative to `%rip`, i.e. relative to`0x36`:

```
movl   $0x1,0x0(%rip)  # 36 <main+0x36>
```

Obviously, just putting the absolute address of `shared` via `R_X86_64_32` won't do any good - a more complicated calculation is needed and this is what `R_X86_64_PC32` is for.

Once again, because of the small code model the compiler can assume, that 32-bit rip-relative offset is enough (and thus  the relocation `R_X86_64_PC32` and not `R_X86_64_PC64` is used) and the placeholder is only 4 bytes wide.

Taken from the x86-64-abi, the formula for the relocation is (section 4.4):

```
result = S+A-P (32bit-word, i.e. the lower 4 bytes of the result) 
S = the value of the symbol whose index resides in the relocation entry 
A = the addend used to compute the value of the relocatable field 
P = the place (section offset or address) of the storage unit being relocated (computed using r_offset)
```

That means:

- `S` is the address of the `shared` variable.
- `A` is `-8` (can be seen for example by calling `readelf -r a.o` or `objdump -r a.o`),  because there is difference of 8 byte between the offset of the relocation `0x2e` and the actual `%rip` - `0x36`.
- `P` is the offset of the  relocation, i.e. `0x26`. `P-A` is the address in `%rip`.

As you can see, the result is not `S` as in the case of `R_X86_64_32` above, but `S - (P-A)`. It also can be seen in the resulting binary - different values will be patched at the placeholders for these two different relocation types.

---

[There](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/03/understanding-the-x64-code-models) is a great article about this topic from Eli Bendersky.