# Why can compiler assume that the address of a global variable will fit 32bit?

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64

When looking at the assembler (see on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/ZQnXFo)) of this simple function

```
extern int global;
void doit(int *);
void call_doit(){
    doit(&global);
}
```

a 32bit value is used to hold the address of `global`:

```
call_doit:
        movl    $global, %edi
        jmp     doit
```

I understand, that using 32bit-registers (i.e. `%edi`) here is superior to 64bit-registers (i.e. `%rdi`), because a 2 bytes can be saved (`movl $global, %edi` needs 5 bytes while `movq $global, %rdi` needs 7 bytes + 4 additional bytes if one would not assume that `$global` fits in 32 bits).

(editor's note: compilers actually use 7-byte `lea global(%rip), %rdi` to create a 64-bit address from RIP + 32-bit relative displacement, which compilers can assume is in range for related reasons.  And `movabs $global, %rdi` would be 10 bytes, not 11, for 64-bit absolute addresses.)

But why is the compiler allowed to assume that the address of the global variable will fit these 32 bits?  What guarantees does the compiler have?

---

For a local variable, the compiler uses a 64-bit register to hold a stack address, e.g.:

```
void doit(int *);
void call_doit(){
    int local=0;
    doit(&local);
}
```

results in (see on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/MS3QW4)):

```
call_doit:
        subq    $24, %rsp
        leaq    12(%rsp), %rdi
        movl    $0, 12(%rsp)
        call    doit
        addq    $24, %rsp
        ret
```

Comment: Interesting.  C requires the compiler to be able to handle at least 4095 distinct identifiers in a translation unit, but says nothing about linking the entire program.  Is there a limit to the number of global identifiers that the GNU linker imposes, and relies upon?

Comment: @mhc this is because tail call optimization is only possible in the first case (in the second case you have to adjust %rsp)

Comment: BTW, if you do ever create a program with more than 4GB of global variables, there's a non-zero probability that you're Doing It Wrong.  ;-)

Comment: Maybe 32 bits is the limit of the .data and .bss segments.

Comment: even Clang and ICC generates a 32-bit move for the global case. If you change to C++ you'll have more compilers to test, and among those Zapcc and ellcc also emit `movl    $global, %edi`

Comment: GCC has a `-mcmodel=` option that might influence this.